# PostgreSQL - Getting statistical data

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I need to collect some statistical information in my application.
I have a table of users (tb_user)
Every time a new user accesses the application, it adds a new record in this table, ie, one line for each user. The main field are **id** and **date_hour** (timestamp for the first time user accessed the application).

**tb_user**

```
id (bigint) | date_time (timestamp with time zone)
 1          |  2012-01-29 11:29:50.359-03
 2          |  2012-01-31 14:27:10.359-03
```

**I  need get:**

**amount average users by day, week and month**

Example:

by day: 55.45

by week : XX.XX

month: XX.XX

***EDIT:***

My best solution was:

```
WITH daily_count AS (SELECT COUNT(id) AS user_count FROM tb_user)
SELECT user_count, tbaux2.days, (user_count/tbaux2.days) FROM daily_count, 
    (SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM (t2.diff) ) + 1 AS days
     FROM
       (with tbaux AS(SELECT  min(date_time) AS min FROM tb_user)
       SELECT (now() - min) AS diff
       FROM tbaux) AS t2) AS tbaux2
GROUP BY user_count, tbaux2.days
```

But this solution only worked with EXTRACT (DAY ... With weeks and month did not work

Any help is welcome.

Alternatively:

```
SELECT user_count, tbaux2.days, (user_count/tbaux2.days) AS userPerDay, ((user_count/tbaux2.days) * 7) AS userPerWeek, ((user_count/tbaux2.days) * 30) AS userPerMonth
```

**EDIT 2:**

Based on responses from @Bruno, there are some considerations:

When I asked the question, in really I requested a way to select data by day, month and year. I believe that the search that I posted and @Bruno refined, should be interpreted as average of **"a day, every 7 days and every 30 days"** and not by days, weeks and months. I believe that if it is interpreted  in this way, there not will be problems of gender-quoted in example (10% drop). I believe this approach of "every" is answer I need in moment, so will sign this answer.

I suggest as an improvement of post:

- Consider only closed day  in result (not collect users of the current day, and not counting the current day in division)
- The result is two numeric digits.
- New research  considering a data really per week and per month.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll have to write a query that calculates an agrregate on subsets of your data.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should look into [aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) (min, max, count, avg), which go hand in hand with [`GROUP BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY). For date-based aggregations, [`date_trunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html) is also useful.

For example, this will return the number of rows per day:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', date_time) AS day_start,
       COUNT(id) AS user_count FROM tb_user
    GROUP BY date_trunc('day', date_time);
```

You can then do the daily average using something like this (with [a CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html)):

```
WITH daily_count AS (SELECT date_trunc('day', date_time) AS day_start,
       COUNT(id) AS user_count FROM tb_user
    GROUP BY date_trunc('day', date_time))
SELECT AVG(user_count) FROM daily_count;
```

Use `'week'` instead of day for the weekly counts, and so on (see `date_trunc` documentation).

**EDIT:** (Following comment: average up to and including 5/1/2012, i.e. before the 6th.)

```
WITH daily_count AS (SELECT date_trunc('day', date_time) AS day_start,
       COUNT(id) AS user_count
    FROM tb_user
       WHERE date_time >= DATE('2012-01-01') AND date_time < DATE('2012-01-06') 
    GROUP BY date_trunc('day', date_time))
SELECT SUM(user_count)/(DATE('2012-01-06') - DATE('2012-01-01')) FROM daily_count;
```

What's above is over-complicated, in this case. This should give you the same result:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)/(DATE('2012-01-06') - DATE('2012-01-01'))
    FROM tb_user
       WHERE date_time >= DATE('2012-01-01') AND date_time < DATE('2012-01-06');
```

**EDIT 2:** After your edit, I guess what you're after is just a single global average for the entire period of existence of your database, rather than groups by month/week/day.

This should give you the average number of rows per day:

```
WITH total_min_max AS (SELECT
        COUNT(id) AS total_visits,
        MIN(date_time) AS first_date_time,
        MAX(date_time) AS last_date_time,
    FROM tb_user)
SELECT total_visits/((last_date_time::date-first_date_time::date)+1) AS users_per_day
    FROM total_min_max
```

(I would replace `last_date_time` with `NOW()` to make the average over the time until now, rather than until the last visit, if there's no recent visit.)

Then, for daily, weekly, and "monthly":

```
WITH daily_avg AS (
    WITH total_min_max AS (SELECT
            COUNT(id) AS total_visits,
            MIN(date_time) AS first_date_time,
            MAX(date_time) AS last_date_time,
        FROM tb_user)
    SELECT total_visits/((last_date_time::date-first_date_time::date)+1) AS users_per_day
        FROM total_min_max)
SELECT
         users_per_day,
         (users_per_day * 7) AS users_per_week,
         (users_per_month * 30) AS users_per_month
    FROM daily_avg
```

This being said, conclusions you draw from such statistics might not be great, especially if you want to see how it changes.

I would also normalise the data per day rather than assuming 30 days in a month (if not per hour, because **not all days have 24 hours**). Say you have 10 visits per day in Jan 2011 and 10 visits per day in Feb 2011. That gives you 310 visits in Jan and 280 visits in Feb. If you don't pay attention, you could think you've had a almost a 10% drop in terms of number of visitors, so something went wrong in Feb, when really, this isn't the case.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your answer.
This not exactly what I need.
This type of search returns only average considering only days that have records , however I need to consider the whole period. example, considering that a user has accessed on 01/01/2012 (MM / DD / YY) and another on 01/05/2012 the average shown in your example would be "1",but I need a search considering the range of between 01 days and 05 that did not occur insertion, showing the result: 0.4. Any Idea ?

Comment: For this, I would use a `WHERE` clause in the CTE (the `SELECT` within `WITH`) to restrict the date range using `date_time`, then use `SUM` instead of `AVG` and divide by the number of days in the range.

Comment: I could make a few changes: 
WITH daily_count AS (SELECT date_trunc('day', date_time) AS day_start, 
       COUNT(id) AS user_count FROM tb_user
       WHERE ??????
    GROUP BY date_trunc('day', date_time))
SELECT SUM(user_count) FROM daily_count;
I don't know  some way to restrict the dates and to count the days.

Comment: @vcltzac, I've just edited my answer with an example. If you're not familiar with this sort of `WHERE` clause, I'd suggest going through a few SQL tutorials, otherwise, there's no point for you to try to understand or write more complex queries.

Comment: But to develop this research is not enough to be familiar with the WHERE clause, because it is not a trivial condition. I edited my question and enter my partial solution.

Comment: Sorry if it's a dumb question, but what did you mean by *‘not all days have 24 hours’* ?

Comment: @AndriyM some countries implement Daylight Saving Time. Timezones always matter. See: http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php

Comment: +n for this detailing.

Comment: @RageCompex Basically, in many countries, we change for summer/winter time, so in those cases at least 1 day in the year has 23 hours and another one 25 hours. It's the kind of things many programmer neglect, but that can cause a few bugs or miscalculations. If you expect something relatively stable per hour, you could get roughly a 5% "unexplained" variation for your daily stats on those days.