# PostgreSQL: counting elements per hour and position

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a PostgreSQL table with a structure like this

```
id    elementid    timestamp                providerid    x    y
1     1            2014-10-01T00:00:00Z     12           12   18
2     1            2014-10-01T00:10:00Z     12           14   18
3     1            2014-10-01T00:15:00Z     12           16   20
4     2            2014-10-01T00:50:00Z     12           12   18
5     2            2014-10-01T01:10:00Z     12           14   18
6     2            2014-10-01T01:15:00Z     12           16   20
7     7            2014-10-01T00:00:00Z     14           12   18
8     7            2014-10-01T00:10:00Z     14           14   18
9     7            2014-10-01T00:15:00Z     14           16   20
```

**And I want to count the number of different `elementid` belonging to the same `providerid` per hour and position**.

An example

Between **00:00 and 01:00**, in the box defined by **xmin=12, ymin=18, xmax=16, ymax=20**, there are **2 elements** belonging to **providerid 12** (4 first records: element with elementid = 1 and element with elementid = 2). So, the count is **2 elements per hour, for providerid = 12**.

As you can see, **I'm really dealing with moving elements**. So, in that time frame (1 hour), I get the element 1 in 3 different positions and the element 2 in one position. So, a total of 2 elements, belonging to the same provider (providerid = 12).

Then, my resultset should look like this:

```
providerid              start_time                end_time    num_elements
        12    2014-10-01T00:00:00Z    2014-10-01T01:00:00Z               2
```

And I want **the same for each provider**.

I guess the response is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176205/postgresql-getting-statistical-data), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818524/moving-average-based-on-timestamps-in-postgresql) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428951/selecting-an-average-of-records-grouped-by-5-minute-periods), but still didn't find the solution. Any help is really appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `COUNT( DISTINCT ... )` ?

```
SELECT t1."providerid",
       s.start_time,
       s.end_time,
       COUNT( DISTINCT "elementid" ) As num_elements
FROM table1 t1
JOIN start_end_time s
ON t1."timestamp" BETWEEN s.start_time AND s.end_time
GROUP BY 
       t1."providerid",
       s.start_time,
       s.end_time
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b55a8/2